# web app not doing substraction operation-Python

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am trying to create a web app and one of it´s features is to add, subtract and multiply numbers that are implemented as a list separated by spaces, they all work but the subtracting is giving me weird results, for example, if I try to type in 6 2, the expected result may be 4 but instead it is now giving me -2, I believe this is because it is subtracting from index 0 so it'l just give the second number, so I changed it to  int(form_text[0]) but now it gives me the IndexError: string index out of range and I'm sure I typed two numbers.

```
@app.route('/add_numbers', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_numbers_post():
# --> ['5', '6', '8']
# print(type(request.form['text']))
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('add_numbers.html')

elif request.method == 'POST':
    form_text = request.form['text'].split()
    print(request.form['text'].split())
suma_total = 0
resta_total = int(form_text[0])
multiplicacion_total = 1
try:
    for str_num in form_text:
        suma_total += int(str_num)
        resta_total -= int(str_num[1])
        multiplicacion_total *= int(str_num)
    return render_template('add_numbers.html', result_suma=str(suma_total), result_multiplicacion=str(multiplicacion_total), result_resta=str(resta_total))
except ValueError:
    return "Easy now! Let's keep it simple! 2 numbers with a space between them please"
```

Comment: If you are substracting from 0 in each iteration, it will always be a negative value. 
ie: (init) -> resta_total == 0, resta_total -= 6 -> resta_total == 6, resta_total -= 2 -> resta_total == 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are subtracting all numbers from "for str_num in request.form["text"].split()" from resta_total which is 0. The resta_total variable should be set to the first int in request.form["text"].split(). Try this...

```
@app.route('/add_numbers', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_numbers_post():
# --> ['5', '6', '8']
# print(type(request.form['text']))
form_text = []
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('add_numbers.html')

elif request.method == 'POST':
    form_text = request.form['text'].split()
    print(request.form['text'].split())
suma_total = 0
resta_total = int(form_text[0]) - int(form_text[1])
multiplicacion_total = 1
try:
    for str_num in request.form['text'].split():
        suma_total += int(str_num)
        multiplicacion_total *= int(str_num)
    return render_template('add_numbers.html', result_suma=str(suma_total), 
result_multiplicacion=str(multiplicacion_total),result_resta=str(resta_total))
except ValueError:
    return "Easy now! Let's keep it simple! 2 numbers with a space between them please"
```

Please note that this assumes there is a value for form_text[0]. Also you can change the for loop to "for str_num in form_text".

To handle subtraction of more than two integers...

```
idx = 0
for str_num in form_text:
    suma_total += int(str_num)
    multiplication_total *= int(str_num)
    if idx > 0:
        resta_total -= int(str_num)
    else:
        resta_total = int(str_num)
    idx += 1
```

Comment: meop2664 Thanks for the response I tried it but then it gave me an error so I tweaked it a bit and then it  gave me IndexError: string index out of range
Chech the post I edited with the changes.

Comment: @AllanReyes you can't do str_num[1]. That is trying to index through the string from form_text which is either "6" or "2". If the input is always two numbers you can achieve the subtraction part with my edits above. Look at the "resta_total" instantiation. If you want to be able to input more than two integers at a time you will need to change the for loop to keep track of the index you are on. I will edit my post to display how this can be done.